# not able to upload .c file to git

Tags: ios, xcode, git

Hi am facing an issue while trying to upload my ios project to git. 
All files get uploaded except a file called "sqlite3.c"

And when i try to build for device its throwing up this error 
clang: error: no such file or directory:

When i change build target to ios simulator it builds fine and the missing file sqlite3.c gets generated automatically. 
Please let me know if you have any info about the problem of file missing in git or about error while building for device as target in xcode.
Thanks
Santosh

Comment: If the file is generated it should not be in git and is it in the local repo? Yo need to provide more info

Comment: yes Mark, the file is generated in the local repo once i build the project (only when i build for simulator as target) but is missing when i freshly download the project.

Comment: If generated then it won't be in the download - generated has a specific meaning in builds are you using this term correctly?

Comment: No its not available in the git i checked all files in git except the sqlite3.c file all are present.

Comment: Generated here means after i download the project into my local repository and build the project the file is generated and saved in my local.  But the issue is this doesnt happen on the build server.